# Hiding and showing elements with v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a radio button, If the person selects "Yes" I want to render an additional div. If "Yes" was selected and then they select "No" I want to hide that div again, I tried to use v-if and a trigger with @click but it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

```
<b-row>
    <b-col cols="6">
        <b-form-group>
            <label>Would you like to show the div?</label>
                <b-form-radio name="asociado" id="asociado"  @click="asociado = true">Yes</b-form-radio>
                <b-form-radio name="asociado" id="noasociado" @click="asociado=false">No</b-form-radio>
        </b-form-group>
     </b-col>
</b-row>

<b-row v-if="asociado">
    <h1>hi</h1>
</b-row>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            asociado: false,
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the creators of the `b-radio-input` component are not emitting a `click` event.  If this is BootstrapVue, as suggested, you can see the events they emit [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-radio#comp-ref-b-form-radio-group-events).

There's a few workarounds.

1. Use a `@change` event instead

   ```
   <b-form-radio name="asociado" id="asociado"  @change="asociado = true">Yes</b-form-radio>
   <b-form-radio name="asociado" id="noasociado" @change="asociado = false">No</b-form-radio>
   ```
2. Use `v-model` and `value` (I would suggest this one)

   ```
   <b-form-radio name="asociado" id="asociado" :value="true"  v-model="asociado">Yes</b-form-radio>
   <b-form-radio name="asociado" id="noasociado" :value="false" v-model="asociado">No</b-form-radio>
   ```
3. Use a `.native` modifier on the click event.

   ```
   <b-form-radio name="asociado" id="asociado"  @click.native="asociado = true">Yes</b-form-radio>
   <b-form-radio name="asociado" id="noasociado" @click.native="asociado = false">No</b-form-radio>
   ```
4. Use the `b-radio-group` component as @user1538301 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Bootstrap-Vue (which it looks like based on your markup)

You need to use the [`b-radio-group`](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-radio/) component; try this markup:

```html
<b-row>
    <b-col cols="6">
        <b-form-group>
            <label>Would you like to show the div?</label>
            <b-radio-group v-model="asociado" :options="[{text: 'Yes', value:
                true}, {text: 'No', value: false}]">
            </b-radio-group>
        </b-form-group>
    </b-col>
</b-row>

<b-row v-if="asociado">
    <h1>hi</h1>
</b-row>
```